# SSL not working for the certain path

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

This is my configuration for ssl:

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
    DocumentRoot /path/todirectory/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/server.key

    <Directory "/path/todirectory/">
        Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all    
    </Directory>

    <Location />
        AuthType shibboleth  
        require shibboleth
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

https://servername works but https://servername/path/todirectory does not work. I get 404 what might be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/path/todirectory/` is the physical path on the server that the files reside at.

So, `https://servername/` maps to the index in `/path/todirectory/` (your `DocumentRoot`), while `https://servername/path/todirectory` would map to the physical directory `/path/todirectory/path/todirectory/`, which probably doesn't exist.

What content are you expecting that it should load when you request `https://servername/path/todirectory`?

Comment: I have php files there.

Comment: @adsad Where are the files?  And which file do you expect to be used when you send that specific request?

Comment: I think I got the problem. I enter my domain name it worked. ServerName: mydomain.com but when I remove it it does not work with public ip address. that's weird.

Comment: @adsad That's likely because there's a different SSL listener elsewhere in your config which is unintentionally getting the request - check the output of `apachectl -S` to find any strays.

Comment: default server myip (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
         port 443 namevhost myip (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
         port 443 namevhost myip (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1007)
      alias myip

Comment: @adsad Yup, so there's two - `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`'s copy is probably the one that you don't want to have in use.

Comment: I think I got to delete ssl.conf file?

Comment: @adsad It probably has some stuff at the top that you still need - instead, you probably want to just comment out its `<VirtualHost>` block.